# gstreamer gstrtpbin sender/receiver in the same pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I wish to build a single gstreamer pipeline that does both rtp audio send and receive.

Based on the examples (few as they are) that I've found, here is my almost working code.

(the program is written in Rexx, but it's pretty obvious what is happening, I think.  Here, it looks a lot like bash!).  Line catenation char is comma.  The "", bits just insert blank lines for readability.

```
rtp_recv_port = 8554
rtp_send_port = 8555

 pipeline =  "gst-launch -e",
         "",
            "gstrtpbin",
            "   name=rtpbin",
         "",
            "udpsrc   port="rtp_recv_port,     -- do-timestamp=true
            '  ! "application/x-rtp,media=audio,payload=8,clock-rate=8000,encoding-name=PCMA,channels=1" ',
            "  ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0",
         "",
            "rtpbin. ",
            "  ! rtppcmadepay",
            "  ! decodebin         ",
            '  ! "audio/x-raw-int, width=16, depth=16, rate=8000, channels=1" ',
            "  ! volume volume=5.0 ",
            "  ! autoaudiosink sync=false",
         "",
            "autoaudiosrc          ",
            "  ! audioconvert      ",
            '  ! "audio/x-raw-int,width=16,depth=16,rate=8000,channels=1" ',
            "  ! alawenc           ",
            "  ! rtppcmapay perfect-rtptime=true mtu=2000",
            "  ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_1",
         "",
            "rtpbin.send_rtp_src_1 ",
            "  ! audioconvert",
            "  ! audioresample",
            "  ! udpsink port="rtp_send_port "host="ipaddr

pipeline "> pipe.out"
```

If I comment out the lines after

```
"  ! autoaudiosink sync=false",
```

The receive-only portion works just fine.  However, if I leave those lines in place I get this error:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2582): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
```

So what's suddenly become unlinked?  I'd understand if the error was in the autoaudiosrc portion, but suddenly showing up in the udpsrc section?

Suggestion of help, anyone?

(FWIW) After I get this part working I will go back in and add the rtcp parts or the pipeline.

Comment: I am actually in the same boat Wes. Except mine has to be a live stream of two linux machines sending audio and video to each other in a video call. As soon as I have mine figured out, I am sure I can shed light on this if it is not answered by then.

Comment: Well, it's nice not to be alone.  Thanks in advance for any help.  I finally gave pup and put receiver and sender pipelines in separate threads.  That's working great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pipeline that will send and receive audio (full duplex). I manually set the sources so that it is expandable(you can put video on this as well and I have a sample pipeline for you if you want to do both). I set the `jitter buffer mode` to `BUFFER` because mine is implemented on a network with a TON of jitter. Now, within this sample pipe, you could add all your variable changes (`volume`, your audio source, encoding and decoding etc.).

```
 sudo gst-launch gstrtpbin \ 

 name=rtpbin audiotestsrc ! queue ! audioconvert ! alawenc ! \ 

 rtppcmapay pt=8 ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! \ 
 multiudpsink clients="127.0.0.1:5002" sync=false async=false \ 

 udpsrc port=5004 caps="application/x-rtp, media=audio, payload=8, clock-rate=8000, \ 
 encoding-name=PCMA" ! queue ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0  \ 
 rtpbin. buffer-mode=RTP_JITTER_BUFFER_MODE_BUFFER ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! alsasink
```

I have had issues with the Control(RTCP) packets. I have found that a loop back test is not sufficient if you are utilizing RTCP. You will have to test on two computers talking to each other.

Let me know if this works for you as I have tested on 4 different machines and all have worked.

Comment: YES!  This worked fine after I figured out that I had to have one side be 5002/5004 and the other 5004/5002.  Took a minute or two to Windows-ize it (no alsa, used autoaudiosink).  Tried it between two VMs (one Linux and one Windows) on one host (Mac oddly enough!).  They share the same speakers so the output sounds a lot like FAST morse.  Well done.

Comment: I have not bothered much with RTCP yet as I have not had to worry about jitter or latency mitigation and manipulation as of yet(proof of concept and not full implementation). However, every instance that I have utilized it, RTCP would never really work in loop back. Remember, your src and sink will both send and receive RTCP data. So, in that way, it is slightly different from just a plain old RTP stream.